# Introducing Gladys, an intrepid globetrotter

Tags: geography, mazes, nonogram

**Gladys** has always led an active life full of adventure. As a retiree, she has a lot of free time on her hands and loves to spend it on her two favourite pastimes – travelling and crossword puzzles. Today she embarks on a long journey that will take her halfway across the globe. She will send us postcards from some of her favourite destinations, each accompanied with a puzzle that reveals what place or landmark she is visiting. In the end, we may find out what she got out of her journey.

This is intended to be part 1 of 26 (assuming we all live that long). The answers will be needed in the final puzzle, all others are standalones. Note that while many of Gladys's destinations are obscure, each is notable enough to have its own separate article in the English Wikipedia.

Without further ado, let's hear what Gladys has to say:

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > As you know, today I started my long-awaited journey halfway across the globe. My trip has started very peacefully. I spent a quiet moment in a lovely church which has beautiful stained glass windows and just a wonderful atmosphere. I look forward to writing to you from the places I visit to let you figure out where in the world I'm travelling.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Gladys unchained](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83565)*".</sub>

Comment: nice puzzle, +1! does the spaces on the side columns count as breaks? i mean e.g. can the 8 on the left column be split due to the breaks in boundaries? thanks!

Comment: Thanks @OmegaKrypton! The holes on the side columns don't matter for the nonogram. So the squares next to the holes can be filled in just like any other square. Does that answer your question?

Comment: so may i ask does this count as 1 1 or a 2? thanks! https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORZEF.jpg

Comment: @OmegaKrypton That would count as 1 1. I reuploaded the grid now with thin lines added to the holes, is it clearer this way?

Comment: This reminds me of Picross Luna...

Comment: How are people working these puzzles?  Is there a tool that lets you enter a custom nonogram so you can solve it?  Or are you printing it and working with pencil?  Or using a paint program on the image?

Comment: @KCBaltz The latter for me, at least.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Heinz Memorial Chapel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinz_Memorial_Chapel)

Completed Nonogram

> [image]

Traversed Maze

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

Gladys is at:

> Heinz Memorial Chapel

Solution to Nonogram:

> [image]

Details:

> Traversing the maze from left to right walking through the letters spells Heinz Memorial Chapel