# Gladys unchained

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-clues

<sub>This puzzle is part 2 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. If you're new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today I spent the entire day outdoors. There are so many enjoyable parks and gardens in this area. Who says you can't enjoy nature in a big city? The puzzle I'm sending you is a word chain. The name of my destination consists of two words. Have fun!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> 1. A pope essentially munched alongside me during a period of fasting (7)
>   2. American car's air conditioning is beyond breaking point (7)
>   3. Black Prince, extremely exhausted, abruptly draws back (6)
>   4. Fantastic Potter has Elizabeth I's crown (7)
>   5. Football club's anthem botched by small child (9)
>   6. For every leading actor group, a prediction (8)
>   7. Half of meal prepared before specified time (7)
>   8. Make up a guess about jolly couple's birds (8)
>   9. Minister's corrupt circle (6)
>   10. Permanent building (6)
>   11. Prominent Republican host with a murderous brother (6)
>   12. Real corruption in Karnataka's bordering state (6)
>   13. Saloon outside Kazan's central marketplace (6)
>   14. Senseless gun mob regularly after central banks (4)
>   15. Short person essential to hybrid warfare (5)
>   16. Superman, finally social, upset Kal-El's dad (7)
>   17. Untalented writer has trouble finishing diacritical mark (5)
>   18. Vegetable food course by sun god (6)

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[T-Rex goes cooking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83680)*".</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gladys is in the

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_Necklace.

Clues and solutions:

> ```
> CLEMENT    1. A pope essentially munched alongside me during a period of fasting (7)
> PONTIAC    2. American car's air conditioning is beyond breaking point (7)
> EDWARD     3. Black Prince, extremely exhausted, abruptly draws back (6)
> TREETOP    4. Fantastic Potter has Elizabeth I's crown (7)
> TOTTENHAM  5. Football club's anthem botched by small child (9)
> FORECAST   6. For every leading actor group, a prediction (8)
> ALREADY    7. Half of meal prepared before specified time (7)
> SEAGULLS   8. Make up a guess about jolly couple's birds (8)
> CLERIC     9. Minister's corrupt circle (6)
> STABLE    10. Permanent building (6)
> MCCAIN    11. Prominent Republican host with a murderous brother (6)
> KERALA    12. Real corruption in Karnataka's bordering state (6)
> BAZAAR    13. Saloon outside Kazan's central marketplace (6)
> NUMB      14. Senseless gun mob regularly after central banks (4)
> DWARF     15. Short person essential to hybrid warfare (5)
> NICOLAS   16. Superman, finally social, upset Kal-El's dad (7)
> HACEK     17. Untalented writer has trouble finishing diacritical mark (5)
> RADISH    18. Vegetable food course by sun god (6)
> ```

Many of these were also solved by @hexomino, but I haven't looked at their answers ... *except* that I wasn't able to figure out #10 and peeked at that one, which apparently was actually solved by Chris Cudmore in comments. Kudos to Chris!

Piecing these together we get:

> ```
>   A C E R O F R A W D
>   S N E T T O T N E R
>   T H A H S I D A M A
>   R A C Y D A E R E W
>   E M E . . . R A L D <--
> N E C K . . . L A C E <--
> I T C E R A L A Z I L
> C O A I N U M B A R B
> O P O N T I A C L E A
> L A S E A G U L L S T
> ```

There is one thing I don't understand:

> the *definition* part of #16. The wordplay is clear enough, but the definition has to be "Kal-El's dad" and I am failing to see why that should be NICOLAS rather than either JOR-EL or JONATHAN. [EDITED to add:] Thanks to El-Guest for setting me straight on this one. It turns out that Nicolas Cage *actually named his son Kal-El*. Gosh.

Comment: Kudos. Nice work.

Comment: Thanks! And my apologies if you were near to completion :-). I promise I didn't steal any of your work.

Comment: I'm never sure about the proper etiquette with substantial puzzles made mostly out of small separable parts...

Comment: I think I would have needed at least another half hour of thinking, and that was with Chris Cudmore's assistance. I think the bit in number 16 you're confused about is to do with Kal-El Cage rather than the obvious.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Kal-El is also the son of [this man](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Cage), which should help with the definition.

Comment: In what sense is he the son of that man? ... _Oh_. He actually called his son Kal-El. Good grief. Thanks.

Comment: That was my first response when I googled it....”why is that man coming up in the response?” Good grief is right — no problem! Great solution.

Comment: Amazing work. Just how do you find in what order to insert the words?

Comment: Last letter of each word = first letter of next.

Answer (score 10):

**Partial answer**

**1.** A pope essentially munched alongside me during a period of fasting (7)
Solved by Chris Cudmore

> Clement = mun**c**hed + lent with me in the middle.

**2.** American car's air conditioning is beyond breaking point (7)
Solved by Chris Cudmore

> Pontiac = anagram of point + AC

**3.** Black Prince, extremely exhausted, abruptly draws back (6)

> Edward = **e**xhauste**d** + draw, backwards

**5.** Football club's anthem botched by small child (9)

> Tottenham = Tot + anthem, anagrammed

**6.** For every leading actor group, a prediction (8)

> Forecast = **For e**very + cast (actor group)

**8.** Make up a guess about jolly couple's birds (8)

> Seagulls = anagram of "a guess" around jo**ll**y

**9.** Minister's corrupt circle (6)

> Cleric = anagram of circle

**10.** Permanent building (6)
Solved by Chris Cudmore

> Stable

**11.** Prominent Republican host with a murderous brother (6)

> McCain = M.C. + Cain

**12.** Real corruption in Karnataka's bordering state (6)

> Kerala = **K**arnatak**a** around anagrammed real

**13.** Saloon outside Kazan's central marketplace (6)

> Bazaar = Bar around K**aza**n

**14.** Senseless gun mob regularly after central banks (4)

> Numb = ba**n**ks + g**u**n **m**o**b**

**15.** Short person essential to hybrid warfare (5)

> Dwarf = hybri**d warf**are

**18.** Vegetable food course by sun god (6)

> Radish = Ra + dish

Comment: 2 is rot13(cbagvnp)

Comment: 10 might be a building where you'd keep livestock.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore — such as rot13(fgnoyr)?

Comment: 1 is rot13(pyrzrag)

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I can see where most of this works but how do you incorporate the c at the beginning. Thank you, by the way, some of these are very tricky.

Comment: Essentially munched gives the C

Comment: 4 is easier than you think.   More arboreal than royal.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Thanks for your help, I see what it was from Gareth's answer. Would've taken me a while.