# T-Rex goes cooking

Tags: geography, crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 3 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. If you're new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: "*[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*".</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today I visited an important historic site from the Civil War era. This is the first of many museums I expect to be seeing on my trip. The puzzle looks a little like a tyrannosaurus wearing a cook's hat, don't you think? Have fun! I'll write you again soon from my next destination.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Cry
>   4. Loathing
>   7. Infuriate
>   8. Fred's frequent partner
>   9. Hoover or Poe
>   10. Evil glances
>   11. Doctrine
>   15. Old cloth or Joplin piece
>   16. Glide across ice
>   18. Bourbon ingredient
>   19. The Crocodile Hunter
>   20. Naturally illuminated at night
>   21. Football legend
>
> **Down**
>   1. Waller's piano style
>   2. Cointreau flavour
>   3. Panhandler
>   4. Male pronoun
>   5. L.A. player
>   6. Grown-up fawns
>   11. Renounced
>   12. Elderly women
>   13. Mousepad or yoga cushion
>   14. Become older
>   17. Whale food
>   18. Cut a photograph
>   19. Woman turned into a cow

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Devoted to high culture](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83709)*".</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She is at

> [Tredegar Iron Works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tredegar_Iron_Works)

Filled in crossword grid

> [image]

And the path (thanks to w l in the comments)

> You need to get each snake to eat all the apples in their grid 
>  [image]

Comment: That was fast...

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Thanks, still not sure how to use the letters, though.

Comment: Find a path for the snakes to eat all apples and it will spell two words, the wanted location.

Comment: @wl Thank you, that is a great spot!

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer

Down:

14: Become older

> age