# Gladys spins the wheel

Tags: geography, crosswords, jigsaw-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle is part 5 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > I hope this message finds you well. Today I indulged in a bit of luxury. I booked a nice hotel room, had a massage at the spa, and watched an amazing magic show. I even tried my luck in roulette! But don't worry, I haven't spent my entire travelling budget here so the journey continues.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   2. Social security
>   8. D.C. suburb
>   10. TV channel, sometimes unplugged
>   11. Chief officer or administrator, informally
>   12. Sister of Meg, Jo and Beth
>   14. Jay ____ Garage
>   15. Command for a dog
>   17. Illegitimately seize power
>   19. Unisex first name
>   20. Decorate anew
>   21. Prominent climate change activist
>   22. Name and password haver
>   23. Type of elephant
>   24. Creative work
>
> **Down**
>   1. – mater
>   2. Buddhist temple
>   3. Jealousy
>   4. Cunning canines
>   5. Perpendicular to Manhattan's streets
>   6. Woodwind instrument
>   7. Psyche's partner
>   9. Of extremely high quality
>   13. Director Forman
>   15. Long epic story
>   16. Actress Hatcher
>   18. Long Beach or Busan, for example
>   20. Participate in an election as a candidate

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Horribly broken and just plain wrong](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83781)*".</sub>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

She is at

> [Eldorado Resort Casino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eldorado_Resort_Casino)

Filled crossword

> [image: Filled crossword]

Grey parts

> Taking the grey puzzle pieces and assembling it to a 5x4 rectangle gives the location.