# Horribly broken and just plain wrong

Tags: wordplay, geography, cryptic-clues

<sub>This puzzle is part 6 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today it's back to nature for me. I'm at an ecological reserve which has large areas of practically untouched mangrove wetlands. I have visited some ancient ruins and walked along the beautiful shoreline. This trip is shaping up to be everything I expected and more!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> 1. Pieces of wood called pieces of meat (6)
>   2. Capital city held by slim Alexander (4)
>   3. Public transport vehicles turn intelligent (5)
>   4. Stones endlessly arranged musical sounds (5)

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Watching the game, having a puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83812)*".</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gladys is visiting

> [Sian Ka'an](http://www.visitsiankaan.com/)

The cryptic crossword:

> `S T A K E S S T E A K S`  
>   `L I M A             M A L E`
> `S M A R T           T R A M S`
>     `N O T E S       T O N E S`
>
>  where each cryptic clue can be solved two ways, and the two answers are put into the grid in the *A and *Z positions in alphabetical order.
>  Gladys' location is then read off from the yellow squares. (Obviously hehe)

Unfortunately,

> I had no idea for clue 2.

Fortunately,

> @PilsNot3 is not as dense as I am.  Clue 2 now solved.

For completeness:

> 1. Defs for STEAKS and STAKES; homophone indicator "called" changes one to the other.
>  2. Two capital cities contained in "sliM ALExander" and "sLIM Alexander".
>  3. Public transport TRAMS and intelligent SMART; "turns" reversing one into the other.
>  4. Endless STONE(-s) and NOTES and TONES (musical sounds); anagrind "arranged" changes one to the other.

Comment: For 2, perhaps the two you're looking for are [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima) [ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mal%C3%A9)?

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Gaah.. I never see that clue type.  (Much obliged!)

Comment: It's one of the first ones I tend to look for actually, they're fairly easy to spot. (No problem!)