# Watching the game, having a puzzle

Tags: visual, steganography, geography, nonogram

<sub>This puzzle is part 7 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today I went to see a football game at the local stadium. The atmosphere was loud and intense – one can clearly tell that the people here are passionate about the sport. I have to say I enjoyed the game, even though I had never even heard of either team beforehand. I'm tired and must get to bed now. Long flight tomorrow.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[A cryptic tricolour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83858)*".</sub>

Comment: Intentional typo in letter, "cleraly"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gladys is visiting

> [Estadio Garcilaso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estadio_Garcilaso)

The full nonogram:

> [image]

And if we split and rearrange like this:

> [image]

Then

> Read the blue part, then the red part. The purple is the mixture of them.