# A cryptic tricolour

Tags: geography, anagram, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 8 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > As I'm writing to you, I'm looking at an extremely impressive statue. This marks a big milestone for my trip. I certainly could have stayed in my previous destination for a bit, but the way I have planned the trip means I'm going to spend more time in certain parts of the world than others. I'll write you again soon. Take care!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Comedies face having romantic lead discuss ending (6)
>   2. Disguised con man carrying fashionable spice (8)
>   4. Tax organization fires leading financier, leaving no evidence behind (3)
>   8. Reject rights to consume bird (3)
>
> **Down**
>   2. Create digital copy of unopened container (3)
>   3. Leading automobile innovator's radio broadcast (3)
>   4. Native American's piece of raisin cake (4)
>   5. Bird central to western epic (4)
>   6. Airline buried in disasters (3)
>   7. Formerly central Windows version (2)
>   9. Cat takes on mouse initially (3)
>   10. Woman with habit to turn right before finishing run (3)

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Gladys visits a campus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83888)*".</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image]

Brief clue explanations:

> `*` is anagram, `<` is reversal, `_TEXT_` is hidden word, `A_` or `_A` is first/last letter extraction.
>
>  1A: `FA(R_)CE + S`
>  2A: `C(IN)NAMON*`
>  4A: `(-f_)IR(-_e)S`: parsed as "tax organization = FIRES, "leading financier" leaving, no "evidence behind" "
>  8A: `(EMU_)<`
>
>  2D: `(-s)CAN`
>  3D: `AIR (initials)`
>  4D: `_IN CA_`
>  5D: `_ERN E_`
>  6D: `_SAS_`
>  7D: `_ME_`
>  9D: `TOM (initials)`
>  10D: NUN (some letter change with "run"?)

The location is

> found by anagramming the three regions independently: each makes a word, giving the location **AFRICAN RENAISSANCE MONUMENT**. (This is in Senegal, as shown by the green-yellow-red background representing its flag.)

Comment: This is what we call speed... +1!