# Gladys visits a campus

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 9 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today I wanted to see a local educational institution. It may not be the most exciting tourist destination, but I enjoyed it a lot. Museums and churches are great, of course, but it's nice to get to talk with young people for a change.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.
> >
> > P.S. One rule for today's puzzle: A number is worth two letters!

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   2. Destination of an emigrant trail
>   3. Wanted to tear down a wall
>   4. Program used in AA
>   6. Green vegetable
>   7. 25%
>   8. Historical military ruler
>   9. Segregated urban area
>   11. Musician behind *Live Aid*
>   13. President's daughter
>   15. Waiter or computer
>   16. Object with magical powers
>   17. James Bond
>   18. Burnt colour
>   19. Existing being
>
> **Down**
>   1. Used for dating by archaeologists
>   3. Greatly enjoy
>   5. With sign, light or fighter
>   6. Sydney Harbour or George Washington
>   10. Tropical bird
>   12. Median lethal dose
>   14. Japanese sword
>   15. David Fincher thriller

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[The hearts of gold](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83918)*".</sub>

Comment: Fun fact: In Gladys' usage, puzzling is a word like "duckling", not a word like "rolling".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gladys is at

> [**Oran 1 University**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oran_1_University) in Oran, Algeria

The gimmick with this crossword is that

> every square has to be occupied by either two letters or one numeral. For example, 4A is 12 STEP, so you put the 1 and 2 in the first and second squares, then ST and EP in the last two.

Completed gridI:

> (Credit to @Rubio for this much better and cleaner grid! If you want to see the original (terrible) handwritten grid, click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvMBj.jpg).)
>  [image: gladys_campus_completed_grid]

Comment: omg. seriously.  lol

Comment: You're welcome to use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0xxo.png).  My answer had one entry slightly wrong anyway (fixed now) and you beat me by, like, a minute.  To the victor go the spoils.  *\*hat tip\**

Comment: @Rubio are you bashing on my handwriting now? I’ll have you know I spent an entire *20 seconds* writing all that out, and now I feel so offended that I’m going to chuck my device and the rest of the stuff in this room out of the window. (In case you’re concerned, I’m jk, you’re still the best mod :) )

Comment: Oh, I *ninjaed* you... whoops, overreaction there I guess :)

Comment: Yeah, *that* hehe.  Grats :)

Comment: (It belatedly occurs to me that 7A may be "IN" and not "OF", though either seems sufficiently well-fit)