# The hearts of gold

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, mazes, nonogram

<sub>This puzzle is part 10 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > My today's destination is an ancient landmark. This city certainly has no shortage of historic sights! No wonder they call it the █████████████
> >
> > Oops, better strike out that last part. Don't want to be giving out any unintended hints, now do we?
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Fieldwork ahead](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83979)*".</sub>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution to the nonogram:

> [image]

Next:

> Pick up all the hearts in the maze given by the red walls...
>  [image]
>  ...and the one from the blue walls.
>  [image]

And finally:

> Use the outline of the periodic table, and take the elemental abbreviations at each heart you stop by. This gives Fl, Am, I, Ni, O(×2) from red, and Be, Li, S, K from blue: this spells out the location, the **Flaminio Obelisk**.