# Fieldwork ahead

Tags: geography, crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 11 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > I can't believe it has taken this long before I visited the first art gallery of this trip. The place I visited today has a large collection of beautiful works by artists whose names I couldn't possibly spell correctly, let alone pronounce!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Molten rock
>   2. Poker with four hole cards
>   3. Van Halen vocalist
>   4. Caribbean island
>   5. Playwright Coward
>
> **Down**
>   1. Actress with a beach club
>   2. Herbal liqueur
>   3. Unclear, imprecise
>   4. Fictional captain
>   5. 0.2 g

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[For the price of one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84019)*".</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Gladys is at

> [Lauba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauba)

Completed grid

> [image]

Letter locations

> Using the rules of minesweeper we can discover where bombs are hidden 
> [image]

Comment: This is correct. Impressive work, especially since there was an annoying error in the grid (word boundaries were missing). Fixed now...

Comment: I think the order in which I solved it helped: 1D, 2A, 3A, 4A, 3D. Then I came, to 4D and went, aha!