# Gladys's Clashing Cryptic

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

> Dear Puzzling,
>
> Remember me? I have some exciting news for you. I'm starting on a new journey to visit a few wonderful landmarks around the world.
>
> In case you want to follow my travels, I'll send you a crossword puzzle from each destination and you can guess where in the world I'm travelling. Every site I visit has its own article on the English Wikipedia, and each is recognized as a World Heritage Site in one form or another, although not necessarily under the same name that I use. Eventually I dream of completing certain important paperwork which I hope will be a reality in the future, but more on that later.
>
> To make things more interesting, I'll be including some special rule in every puzzle. In today's puzzle, the answer from the "across" clue clashes with the "down" clue in twelve cells. In these cases, you must note down the letter which is alphabetically in the middle of the two clashing letters. For example, B and F (in whichever order) would produce D, since that is the letter halfway between B and F in the alphabet. The twelve letters so produced spell out my today's destination, which is a very impressive coastal landform. Have fun!
>
> Wish you were here!
> Love, Gladys.

<sub>Gladys featured in an earlier puzzle series, which starts at *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*. No knowledge of the previous series is required in these new puzzles.</sub>

[image]

**Across**
1. DOS – a strong and, at first, reliable operating system (5)
5. Fairness requires a large investment (6)
9. Take the exit from the westernmost parts of Lexington Avenue (5)
11. Place for skeleton's abandoned? The end is nigh (5)
14. For example, New York's famous art museum (5)
15. It is said that he would pay attention (4)
16. Head off to left to follow asset I managed (3,4)
17. Excellent papers providing help (3)
18. "Examination of written piece", Earl Grey possibly said (3, abbr.)
19. Brown's successor ultimately stood behind initially continuing in the EU (4)
20. Teach running in gym class, having worked regularly to lose weight, and it bears fruit (5,4)
22. Periodically serve a Northern man (4)
24. Mediterranean island's decisive strikes (3)
25. Repeatedly sit up to get these top awards? Poppycock! (3)
26. Fundamentalist group's target's introduction: alcohol prohibition (7)
28. German sausage for spoiled child (4)
29. Extreme occasions in revolutionary upheaval (5)
32. Awfully 33 across fees for lodging (5)
33. Tough gangster nibbled sandwiches (5)
34. Unruly execs finally confess undue indulgence (6)
35. Woman's 50-50 odds in idea to go after euros (5)

**Down**
1. Order for dropping temperature in mountain mist surrounding mystical Tibet (11)
2. Moroccan city's backers: relief statue was… (3)
3. …reportedly erected – or demolished? (5)
4. Collection firm's position confirmed (3)
5. Small, small expression of human creativity describing Romeo and Juliet? (11)
6. Capital's abandoned before start of October (5)
7. Letter returned to you, in French (4)
8. Drunk Eton fellows interchanged extremities in faculty hotspot (11)
10. 7 down, dab, fraction (3)
12. Los Angeles ballers that traded out Ball – Kobe's #1 among them? (6)
13. By the sound of it, more introverted hobbits live here (5)
16. Small air conditioner container (3)
18. Most reasonable to be 18 across around the home – but only one time (6)
20. Talk incessantly of Captain Hook perhaps missing an eye, as it's said (5)
21. Sharon gets naked a lot (3)
23. Moral depravity showing up in messy backyard (5)
25. Soviet workers' group taking out leader of syndicate (5)
27. Desire for an extended period of time (4)
28. Party town's top spot (3)
30. Operation #2 in Puzzling Stack Exchange (3)
31. Honorific that's occasionally sordid (3)

---

<sub>Gladys will return in *[Gladys's Misprinted Cryptic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101403)*.</sub>

Comment: Welcome back, Gladys! I don't think I've said this before, but it was Gladys's travels that originally got me into PSE... Looking forward to watching Deusovi solve them all while I'm asleep! ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The completed grid (with clashing squares containing first Across letters, then Down letters):

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

And from averaging the letters in each square (top to bottom, left to right), the answer is spelled out:

> Gladys' destination today is **LULWORTH COVE**!

Comment: [Nice location](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5956/17) :-)