# Gladys's Misprinted Cryptic

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This is part 2 of the puzzle series. Part 1 is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101133).</sub>

---

> Dear Puzzling,
>
> Today, I'm taking a tour of historic sites in an ancient city. The crossword has 24 clues containing an extra letter, which you must remove before solving. The results of the removals are not required to be real words, as long as both the definition and wordplay portions of the clue work after its removal. The extra letters spell out an instruction on how to extract the two-word final answer, which is eight letters long.
>
> Wish you were here!
> Love, Gladys.

[image]

**Across**
1. Cave dwellers regularly ignored odd lumps (4)
4. Indiscreet spy agency infiltrates heart of Alaska Oil (7)
9. People living in Japan's education centre, in university? (4)
10. Comedian Michael and Al in agony (5)
11. Dig by working for old surveyor, Jeremiah (5)
12. Two men captured in one area's extreme points (6)
13. A tour entering Northern European capital's landscape (6)
15. African (native Kenyan) sampling sandwiches (5)
16. The most essential among pilgrimages (after Hajj), regularly held within Kuwait's borders, turned away Muslim country's inhabitant (5)
21/30. Director of HR and I prevent her running around, interrupting the Kennedys? (11,5)
22. Khan's angered Shiva (5)
24. LA doctor takes drug for a specific purpose (2,3)
27. Legendary #99, working with large part of ice (6)
28. Soak all strange animals in Australia (6)
29. Mane of lion finally thrown in lake (5)
30. *(See 21 across)*
31. For example, tale of an Insect King (4)
32. Christian symbols for fanatic sects – or fundamentalists, ultimately (7)
33. Area clear, lifeless (4)

**Down**
1. Imprisoned by bold, nice, kind man's foremost foe? (3,4)
2. Rage – a little annoyance made one cross, cross (7)
3. Nozzle is left broken on suit (5)
5. The last of siblings came to be no different (4)
6. It might make one cry to accept investigator's view (7)
7. William is skinned, revealing bones (4)
8. Goals? Amos has one (4)
14. Maybe Manfred von Richthofen took heroin? Smart (4)
17. Ketchum's cable to primarily surround dustbins (7)
18. Kit's used for dilution as the river surrounds tavern (7)
19. Sandwich shop from Indian city announced (4)
20. Advance for grain swung (7)
23. East Asian region's gold displayed in IKEA (5)
25. Carry out orders, evacuating entrance (4)
26. Stereotypical feature of Angeles Mesa: level two feet below house's entrance (4)
27. One associated with tails of dogs – Marshall, Rubble and Skye, maybe (4)

---

<sub>Gladys will return in *[Gladys's Gridless Cryptic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101619)*.</sub>

Comment: Is the "left" in 3D meant to be there?

Comment: @Deusovi I can see why you'd think it shouldn't be there, but the "left" in 3d is actually needed.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

From the misprints, we get

> the instruction "DIAGONAL LETTERS CLOCKWISE". Reading the letters on the outer corners clockwise, then going one square inwards diagonally and reading those letters, gives us the answer: **OLD CAIRO**!