# Gladys's Mismatching Cryptic

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This is part 9 of the puzzle series. Part 1 is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101133).</sub>

---

> Dear Puzzling,
>
> Today I'm visiting a small town to marvel at some fantastic examples of Renaissance architecture. Sadly, this is also the last destination of my trip this time. I will send you one more crossword later where you can put to use the answers you have gathered up from these puzzles.
>
> In this crossword, the wordplay of 24 clues produces one extra letter which is not used in the answer of the clue. The extra letters, in clue order, spell out an instruction on how to extract the final answer, which is ten letters long.
>
> Wish you were here!
> Love, Gladys.

[image]

**Across**
2. Piece of land Rome dealt to Greek princess, according to legend (9)
9. Err, is Gladys like 1 down? (5)
11. Gradually destroy Dover jumping with energy (5)
13. File charges against backers of mainstream pro wrestling (4)
14. Raved about religious text (4)
15. "Blue" states anticipating Yankee Democrats' primaries? (3)
19. Changed into certain exchange between two or more parties (11)
21. Brian played with New York team, making comeback as vital part (5,4)
23. Beardless Scotsman's family's paradise: leader of Englishmen transported to the West (5-6)
30. Adolescent clubber's support (3)
32. Skip a film's odd parts depicting kingdom (4)
33. A shelter for animals left for Middle Easterner (4)
35. South Indian's capital punishment finally overturned (5)
36. Message entered initially by angry 35 across (5)
37. Irishmen christen ocean-going passenger ships (9)

**Down**
1. Extremely selfish American seen with Hawaii fish (5)
2. New mural marker of Russian-Chinese border (4)
3. Americans waged war here, casually napalm striking friend (3)
4. Near Rhode Island, suddenly change direction to Ohio, say (5)
5. One letter of large book supported by vegans, essentially (5)
6. Kingdom's final proclamations of law for health practicioners (6)
7. Haircuts for parties (3)
8. Democrat showed up in a site of a high-profile death (6)
10. Say, Dorian Stooge entertaining Edward, briefly (4)
12. Angry, incoherent speech managed by Tesla (4)
16. Extremely small piece of central Mississippi destroyed in a hurricane? (4)
17. Shop keepers' heart and throat problem (5)
18. At last, Jobs seen with the very top among iProducts: Apple consumer tool designed for use in cooking? (5)
20. Yankee following Sir Walter's Beamer? (6)
21. Clinton lost heart in Paris 1 down? (4)
22. It is followed by football league claiming empty industrial land dedicated for new construction (6)
24. International System of Units headed by Chinese dynasty's standardization body (4, *abbr.*)
25. Inhabitant of southern Africa – a Zulu – visiting southwestern India (5)
26. Excessively masculine people: "The bill of fare has no wings!" (2-3)
27. One classy woman and man (4)
28. Dignified, novel bronze pieces shown up (5)
29. Platform of Donald's significant other's not taken seriously, in the end (4)
31. Bird that is essentially immune (3)
34. Supporting rebels' leader, provide weapon package (3)

---

<sub>Gladys will return in *[Gladys's Gapped Cryptic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104852)*.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Gladys' current location is

> found by looking at the extra letters, which spell out "EVERY NINTH LETTER ON THE RIM". Starting with the S in the upper left and going clockwise, taking every ninth letter, spells out the answer: [**SABBIONETA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbioneta), a small town in northern Italy.