# Gladys's Gapped Cryptic

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #43: Variety Crossword Grids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7062)</sup>

---

<sub>This is part 10 of the puzzle series. Part 1 is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101133).</sub>

> Dear Puzzling,
>
> They say there's no place like home, but for people who love nothing more than being on the move and visiting new exciting places, what really counts as home? While travelling has certainly become more accessible in recent decades, there is still a lot of bureaucracy one must be prepared for when crossing borders from one country to another. Sometimes I wish there was one standard form one could fill to get the permission to travel anywhere in the world. That may sound completely outlandish in 2020, but let's not forget that plenty of things that we take for granted today must have sounded equally improbable for past generations. If you've been following closely, maybe you can figure out what the people of the future might call this all-encompassing traveller's paperwork!
>
> The nine "around" answers running the entire way around the grid are the answers to the nine previous puzzles, in the order they appeared in the series. Because there is too much space in the grid, some cells must be left empty. Gray cells must be filled, pink cells must be empty, and white cells can be either empty or filled. All "around" clues run clockwise, and all axial ("inward") clues run from the outer edge of the grid towards the centre.
>
> For each "inward" clue, note the location of the first empty cell in that answer's grid entry after inserting the answer into the grid. Select the letter that is at the same position in the clue, counting from the start. (For example, if the first empty cell in the grid entry is its third cell, select the third letter of the clue.) Then repeat this process from the other end – note the location of the last empty cell in the grid entry counting from the end of the grid entry backwards, and select the letter in the same position in the clue when counting backwards from the end of the clue. The selected letters, first all the forward ones and then all the backward ones in clue order, spell an instruction for finding out the final answer.
>
> Thanks again for following my travels. Until next time! Take care.
>
> Love, Gladys.

[image]

**Around**
3. Material for celebration in Lincoln (5)
6. Second-rate work style of Mr. Parker, in shortened form (3)
9. Pushing back debut of famous Seoulite, one engaged in espionage (3)
11. 28 inward throwing away empty container frequently (3)
27. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
32. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
33. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
34. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
35. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
36. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
37. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
38. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
39. *(Answer from earlier puzzle)*
40. Among morning droplets, Romeo made a picture (4)
41. Seat with grease stain? (6)
42. Moment of silence enshrining commanders at the front (3)
43. Burdened youngster extremely exhausted (5)

**Inward**
1. Otherwise, in act of political group (7)
2. Criminal went in Mogadishu's centre, which is like Tokyo and New York City (7)
4. Binding order about infiltrating European Commission, established superficially, taken back (6)
5. A White House family's vehicles circling entrance to highway (6)
6. To lay with Angeleno miss leads to multiple instances of unruliness? (7)
7. Omitting central part of overture, surprisingly showing an artist's opuses? (6)
8. Light work in retirement covered by doc in ciphertext (6)
9. Unholy deeds supported by terrible man in *One Thousand and One Nights* story (6)
10. Actor Joe's role finally dropped from piece's setup (5)
12. Useless top cut from trendy deciduous plant (6)
13. Elite ruler, leader of Persia, returns (5)
14. Dog's breakfast after Gladys repeated point (4)
15. Mikhail – the chess champion – is trailing? Gloat without initially appearing like leader in headlines (7)
16. Potter, Trump mostly against ending of sumo, popular martial art in Japan (4)
17. Switch, at last, wood wheel used for steering (4)
18. Shown retreating, ruler has essentially no-one to prepare food (5)
19. Disturb penitentiary (4)
20. Strange play about defining "bottom": "Related to the rump in anatomy" (5)
21. Felonious bunch taking control of a kingdom neighbouring Ammon (4)
22. "Much obliged for the introductions!" – Onetime prominent member of the GOP (4)
23. Broadcast: He's in – Earl, the jazz pianist… (5)
24. …playing solo for city bordering the Atlantic Ocean (4)
25. Ultimately industrious, the man would start to secure places to store rakes (5)
26. Romanov finally seen alongside honeymoon couple with diamond rings, which is something magical (6)
28. Angelina Jolie's role in *Tomb Raider's Lake Retreat* (4)
29. Skink perhaps in front of retired Doctor Minnelli (6)
30. *Chocolat* star's pianos, found after dance, subject to content removal (4)
31. Please repeat… Witch gutted, then brought back assistant in class? (4)

Comment: A beautiful wrap-up to another satisfying and hugely clever Gladys series. Well done jafe :)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! Had to rewrite this almost completely from scratch, but I'm happy with how it turned out in the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The filled grid:

> I've "cut" the grid at the 12:00 line and unwrapped it, for easier viewing. The blue columns are where it wraps around to the other side.
>  [image]

Clue explanations and extraction:

> [image]

The message says:

> `HIGHLIGHT EIGHT WHITE COLUMNS CLOCKWISE, STARTING FROM PINK CELLS`.
>  When we do that, we get a message spelled out in those columns!
>
>  [image]
>  I've cut the grid in a different place to make it more visible - the highlighted columns, when read in normal reading order, spell out what Gladys' futuristic form is -- a **WORLD CITIZENSHIP APPLICATION**!